# Do I need to declare period delay tablets (Utovlan) at Australian customs?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, health, australia

I am travelling to Melbourne first and then onto Sydney. I am planning to take period delay tablets in my hand luggage. I bought them online from my local pharmacy, so I don't have a prescription form. Shall I need to declare them? I don't want any trouble in customs.

Answer (score 6):

You should declare ALL medicine, whether prescribed or not. I not only tick yes to the question, I also circle the word medicine. In my experience when you get to the officer they look at the form and say "what medicine do you have?" They know which medications are allowed in and which are not. I had prescribed medication with me and brought the prescription label. However nobody asked to look at them, my description of what I had and why was enough for the officer in my case.

For any meds you want to bring there are 3 possibilities:

- it's allowed in no matter what
- it is not allowed in no matter what
- it will be allowed if you declare it and have the right paperwork, but it will be confiscated or you will not be allowed in if you don't declare it

If you were completely sure that it would not be allowed in, and if having it was so important to you that you'd be willing to risk being treated as a smuggler, then I suppose you could try not declaring it and hoping you aren't searched. But I think the smarter approach is to declare everything. If for some reason it's not allowed they will take it from you, but you won't be in trouble because you declared it.

I am not familiar with the medication you mention, but expect it's not regulated the way, say, strong painkiller might be. There is some information available from the Australian government online:

> You do not need to declare medications such as aspirin, paracetamol or Australian over the counter medications.  - http://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Ente/Goin/Arrival
>
> The travellers exemption allows you to bring certain prescribed medicines and medical devices into the country without needing special permission. [...] contraception medications (birth control) - https://www.tga.gov.au/travelling-medicines-and-medical-devices

This seems to support that declaring it and then telling the officer when they ask at the desk should work fine for you.

Comment: Yes I was thinking of declaring it anyway. The medication I am describing is utovlan (I think that is the correct spelling) which delays your period for however long you are taking it. I have no problem declaring it and answering any questions if needed I was just worried about the lack of a doctor's note. I ordered it online but it was checked online by a doctor who asked me questions to make sure I got the right medication. But that does clarify the situation- guess I'm just a bit scared as Australia customs are known for being hard core but if I'm honest all the way.

Comment: You should declare absolutely anything that you have any doubts about. I once travelled to Sydney with a broken collarbone and had some painkillers with me.  On the card, I answered 'yes' to "are you carrying any medication?" question.  I was sent to the "further inspection" queue, where a customs officer asked me what I was carrying.  I honestly told him that it was an over-the-counter painkiller for my broken bone (my arm wasn't in the cast, but it was held up in a sling).  He looked at me, smiled and said something like, "I think we'll let this through" - and I was on my way.